# Count by String and grouping by hour

Tags: mysql, count

I have a problem regarding with one table in my database and I have to query the table.

I want to get the Count of **ACTIVATED** from Card Status and group them by desired branch and by hour as well...

Can you help me in getting my query to work?

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_VERIFIED, '%H') AS hour,
    COUNT(CARD_STATUS) AS California
FROM customer
WHERE
    CARD_STATUS = 'ACTIVATED' AND 
    DESIRED_BRANCH = 'California'
GROUP BY hour
```

My query can only get California... I want to also get the other cities.

Here's the table.

[image]

Here is the **desired output**

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and show meaningful sample input and the desired output?

Comment: okay. I'll edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get only California because DESIRED_BRANCH = 'California'.if you want get count of actived Card_Status group by hour and desired branch your query must look like

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_VERIFIED, '%H') as `hour`, COUNT(CARD_STATUS) as 
`Number_Active` FROM `customer` where CARD_STATUS = 'ACTIVATED' 
group by `hour`,branch
```

Comment: Hmm.. but I want each of my cities to show in a column... do you have a query on how to do that? 
Like there is a row for california, and there is a row for Boston

Comment: since your query group by branch each of branchs will show in a column

Comment: sorry i misunderstand.if you want to display each of branchs in a column,you need to use pivot

Comment: Thnx I'll look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going wrong in mentioning `DESIRED_BRANCH = 'California'` in the where clause. You query should look like below

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_VERIFIED, '%H') as `hour`, DESIRED_BRANCH, COUNT(CARD_STATUS) as 
`Count` FROM `customer` where CARD_STATUS = 'ACTIVATED' group by `hour`,DESIRED_BRANCH
```

This would be grouping by `hour` as well as `DESIRED_BRANCH` as required. You would have to get `DESIRED_BRANCH` as well if it is to be included in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT active_california_hours.hour, COUNT(*) 
FROM (  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_VERIFIED, '%H') as `hour` 
    FROM `customer` 
    where   
    CARD_STATUS = 'ACTIVATED' 
    and DESIRED_BRANCH = 'California') active_california_hours
GROUP BY hour
```